# How to loop till a specific named range?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all rows between named ranges rbTop and rbBottom

```
Range("rbBottom").Value = ""
Range("rbTop").Select
Do While (Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "")
Selection.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
Loop
```

This works, but I want a slightly shorter way

```
Range("rbTop").Select
Do While (Selection.Offset(1, 0).Name <> "rbBottom")  // how to write this line ?
Selection.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
Loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any `Select` or loops:

```
Sub Cull()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range(Range("rbtop"), Range("rbbottom"))
If rng1.Rows.Count > 2 Then rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 2, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```